# Oracle APEX_COLLECTIONS equivalent in Oracle PL/SQL alone

Tags: plsql, collections, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I am using Oracle 11g R2.

I'm purely working in the backend alone using PL/SQL where I need to re-write all PL/SQL code that was used within Oracle APEX v4.2 that uses/calls  APEX_COLLECTIONS.

Since I am not able to re-use the APEX_COLLECTION API within PL/SQL without Oracle APEX, can people please advise what the equivalent of APEX_COLLECTIONS is within vanilla PL/SQL?

I will potentially need a maximum of 50 character columns.

I was thinking of global temporary tables but unsure how this would work.

Answer (score 2):

Global temporary table is the feature that APEX_COLLECTIONS try to mimic in the apex envirotment. It is because apex session is not the same as oracle database session.

The way you can implement it feature in PL/SQL, it depends on your current user requeriment. So, if your database session is persistent for all request, then you can (maybe) use global temporary table with the `ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS` clause.

But it is not posible to say widthout requeriment details. I hope it helps.

Apex collections structure is: [Apex Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.1/aeapi/Accessing-a-Collection.html)

```
  COLLECTION_NAME   NOT NULL VARCHAR2(255)
  SEQ_ID            NOT NULL NUMBER 
  C001              VARCHAR2(4000)
  C002              VARCHAR2(4000)
  C003              VARCHAR2(4000)   
  C004              VARCHAR2(4000)   
  C005              VARCHAR2(4000)  
  ...
  C050              VARCHAR2(4000)
  N001              NUMBER
  N002              NUMBER
  N003              NUMBER
  N004              NUMBER
  N005              NUMBER     
  CLOB001           CLOB
  BLOB001           BLOB  
  XMLTYPE001        XMLTYPE
  MD5_ORIGINAL      VARCHAR2(4000)
```

Comment: FYI, the DB session will be persistent for all requests, so a GTT should be fine. My only additional question is, how do I allow for varying column names within a GTT as I believe I need to ensure that the GTT definition already exists?

Comment: @tonyf APEX_COLLECTION have generic column but not varying columns. I will edit the response to add the structure. Then you can create a new estructure like this. You sould understand that there is not exact substitution, you have to do a bit refactor here (I think).